# Maven2 assembly plugin - change root name for tar.gz

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using the assembly plugin to tar.gz up a package.  I am trying to change the root output directory from ${project.name}-{$project.version} to just ${project.name}, but cant seem to find the configuration option for that anywhere.  Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same requirement. According to section [*Using an Alternative Assembly Base Directory* in the docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html), you can add the following directive to your assembly XML file:

```
<baseDirectory>${artifactId}</baseDirectory>
```

which worked for me. Requires Maven assembly 2.2+.

Answer (score 2):

I known this is an old topic but since I've got the same problem.

You can change the name of the root directory by filling the "finalName" property of your assembly plug-in in your pom.xml.

```
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>test</finalName>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

In pom.xml of your project, while configuring your assembly plug-in try to use "outputDirectory" property. For inst.:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <outputDirectory>some/path</outputDirectory>
......
  </configuration>
<plugin>
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem - it merely changes the output directory for the assembly from `./target` to `./some/path` which is not what was asked for.